# What reference to use for prism:Click.Command?

Tags: wpf, reference, prism

I am trying to use the click.command attached property from prism: `prism:Click.Command`. What assembly to I need to reference in my project/xmlns declaration do I need to use it in a XAML control in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** **PRISM 5**

Now support of property were add Command in all inherit from Hyperlink and ButtonBase control items, allow them to be anchor immediately to object of a command in the same way as in WPF.

Old:

```
prism:Click.Command=""
```

New:

```
Command=""
```

Example:

```
<Button 
 Content="Change Text" 
 Command ="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it in the [Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.click%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) namespace?

Also from the link:

Assembly:  Microsoft.Practices.Prism (in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Click class is available in below namespace. you have to add **Assembly Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll** reference.

```
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands
```